# Remove coolbar icon from RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

Using `Eclipse Helios`

[image]

How to remove the icon from `rcp` application. Code Is here...

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {
    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    final ActionSetRegistry reg = WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault()
            .getActionSetRegistry();
    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
         final IActionSetDescriptor[] actionSets = reg.getActionSets();
          final String[] removeActionSets = new String[] {
            "org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet",
            "org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet",
            "org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.convertLineDelimitersTo",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.openExternalFile",
            "org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolsSet",
            "org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet",
            "org.eclipse.update.ui.softwareUpdates",
            "org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles",
            "org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.navigation" };

```
for (int i = 0; i < actionSets.length; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < removeActionSets.length; j++) {
        if (removeActionSets[j].equals(actionSets[i].getId())) {
            found = true;
            final IExtension ext = actionSets[i]
                    .getConfigurationElement().getDeclaringExtension();
            reg.removeExtension(ext, new Object[] { actionSets[i] });
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        continue;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is this an RCP with your own `ActionBarAdvisor` or is it using the Eclipse IDE action bar advisor?

Comment: It is Eclipse IDE action bar advisor. It is by default on my application.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you get those actions contributed by some plugin.

I removed those unwanted actions with the following code in my ApplicationActionBarAdvisor class:

```
private static final String[] actionSetId = new String[] { "org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet", //$NON-NLS-1$
    "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation", //$NON-NLS-1$
    "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.convertLineDelimitersTo", //$NON-NLS-1$
    "org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles", //$NON-NLS-1$
    "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation", //$NON-NLS-1$
    "org.eclipse.ui.NavigateActionSet", //$NON-NLS-1$
    "org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet"}; //$NON-NLS-1$




    private void removeUnWantedActions() {
       ActionSetRegistry asr = WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getActionSetRegistry();
       IActionSetDescriptor[] actionSets = asr.getActionSets();

       IExtension ext = null;
       for (IActionSetDescriptor actionSet : actionSets) {
          for (String element : actionSetId) {
              System.out.println(element);

             if (element.equals(actionSet.getId())) {
                ext = actionSet.getConfigurationElement().getDeclaringExtension();
                asr.removeExtension(ext, new Object[] { actionSet });
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Call “removeUnWantedActions” from the constructor of the ApplicationActionBarAdvisor class.

Basically you need to find out the id of the action you want to remove. The code above removes the following actions:

[image]

Yours should be removed by the code above.

More details in my blog post: http://andydunkel.net/eclipse/java/2011/05/16/remove-unwanted-actions-in-rcp-application.html

Andy

Comment: Have not tried it, but the id for "new" dropdown action is "newWizardDropDown". Try adding that to the list of unwanted actions.

Comment: I found this but unable find solution http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.rcp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fwizards%2Frcp%2Factionbaradvisor.html

Comment: This wont help you much, thats just the manual how to create the toolbar. The problem is, that Eclipse plugin can contribute to the toolbar. In your case some plugin contributes to the toolbar, which you have to indentify and remove, or hide the action with the above apprach. But you need the correct id, you can use the plugin spy to do that (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy). Good luck!